# Jetty8 and Java Bean tmp failed

Tags: java, debian, jetty

```
<code>[ERROR] 2016-01-23 14:48:41,925 [main] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader {} - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#54': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileWritingMessageHandlerFactoryBean#10' while setting bean property 'handler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileWritingMessageHandlerFactoryBean#10': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: failed to initialize MessageHandler; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Destination directory [./taust-ee] could not be created</code>
```

I have this strange problem when running Jetty 8 on Debian 8 Jessie... Don't know where to dig, apps seems to be okay, because on windows and deployed by Jenkins running well. Where can be problem?

Comment: It seems to be a permissions issue. Check if you have permissions to write on this folder

Comment: This folder should be created automatically from war file. I don't know why this one isn't creating, and to be honest I don't even know where to eventually put this folder.

Comment: Okay, I found solution. Wrong permissions for /usr/share/jetty8, fix for this is simply: `chown --recursive jetty /usr/share/jetty8`